# How to get document comments in C# packages?

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I think this question may already be answered at somewhere, but I cannot find that unfortunatelly. If you know, please teach me the URL.

I tried to install C# package via `dotnet add`, OmniSharp.Extensions.LanguageServer and  LanguageExt.Core. However, when I refer to the document comments in editor, there are only signatures, and there are comments for same member at GitHub source code.

So, How to get package with document comments?

Environment

- OS: Windows10 21H2
- devcontainer: dotnet:0-6.0-bullseye-slim
- editor: vscode with C# extension
- package installed via: Package Reference in csproj

Comment: You would need to ask the owner of the repo to include the XML file in the Nuget package.

Comment: Certainly for OmniSharp.Extensions.LanguageServer, the nuget package doesn't include the documentation XML file ([see here](https://nuget.info/packages/OmniSharp.Extensions.LanguageServer/0.19.5): browse into the `lib` folder, and you should see a `.xml` file alongside the `.dll`).

Comment: You could also submit a PR to fix the repo yourself.